# How to specify correct python version for Python Language Server when using multi-root workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-language-server

Does anyone know how to specify correct Python version when use newest VSCode Python extension(`ms-python.python`) with multi-root workspace?

My global python environment is 2.7 and my VSCode project's directory structure is like below:

`root
  ├ .vscode
  │
  ├ childA(Python2.7)
  │  ├ .venv(virtualenv directory created by Pipenv)
  │  └ .vscode
  │
  └ childB(Python3.7)
  │  ├ .venv(virtualenv directory created by Pipenv)
     └ .vscode`

I set pythonPath both child directory's `.vscode/settings.json` file like below:

`"python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python"`

Recently I updated VSCode Python extension, after that, under ChildB directory, Python extension always displays error message like below:

`[Python] invalid syntax, parameter annotations require 3.x [E16]`

I use type annotation like below:

`def add(p1: int, p2: int)
    return p1 + p2`

This error message is returned by Python Language Server that I found here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/blob/7be329643299111cc1f0839d20aa9eb146b0d381/src/Analysis/Engine/Impl/Parsing/Parser.cs#L2088

When I doesn't use multi-root workspace, this error is not displayed.

I think newest Python extension can't recognize correct Python version that I set in `.vscode/settings.json` when I use multi-root workspace.

I want Python Language Server to recognize correct Python version in childB directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes. it's `pls.childB_dir = ".vscode/settings.json"; pls.childB_dir.string_parse_multi_root()`. hope that helps.

Comment: @YangK Thank you for your reply. But I am confused. Is this a VSCode setting?

I can' find 'pls' or `string_parse_multi_root` settings.

Or, if this is a Python code, Where do I have to put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Settings for a multi-root workspace are not specified in a `vscode/settings.json` file but in your [`.vscode-workspace` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But unfortunately it seems that VSCode intellicode plugin and Language Server doesn't recognize multi-root workspace at this time. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-multi-server-sample

Comment: Correct, use Jedi in that case until support has been added: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3017 .

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.